# ¿Cómo recorrer una tabla para obtener el id del registro marcado con un check?

Tags: javascript, html-tabla

soy nuevo en el ambiente Web y necesito recorrer una tabla e identificar cada registro que tenga un CHECK marcado.

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="viewApplicants">
         <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><center>CHECK</center></th>
                    <th><center>ID</center></th>
                    <th><center>FIRST NAME</center></th>
                    <th><center>LAST NAME</center></th>
                    <th><center>DATE</center></th>
                </tr>
        </thead>
            <tbody id="data">
            </tbody>

</table>
```

El siguiente script es para cargar los datos a la tabla

```
<script>
        let url = 'http://localhost:8080/viewApplicants'
        fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => mostrarData(data))
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
            
        const mostrarData = (data) => {
            let body = ''
            for (let i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
                body += `<tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="aplicante"></td>
                    <td>data[i].id}</td>
                    <td>${data[i].firstName}</td>
                    <td>${data[i].lastName}</td>
                    <td>${data[i].date}</td>
                    </tr>`                
            }

            document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = body
        }            
</script>
```

Una vez los datos cargados si el Usuario marca un registro ¿cómo podría obtener el id del registro seleccionado?

Comment: Y si a cada checkbox le asignas una función que maneje el evento onChange y vas guardando los ids en un array? Después sería simplemente tomar ese array y utilizarlo :D

Comment: Por defecto esos registros vienen con el check false, entonces cuando los datos ya están cargados en la tabla es que el usuario debe elegir a cual registro quiere mostrar toda la información.

Comment: Claro, y lo que te aconseje más arriba te serviría para controlar esos estados. El evento onChange se desencadenaría cada vez que el usuario intercatúe con tu elemento checkbox

Comment: Excelente, lo voy a probar. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Si te estancas en algo, edita la publicación, incluye el código JavaScript que has intentado y te ayudamos a resolverlo :D. Éxito colega